# Can't set a cookie using NextJS 9's API Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Typically it seems that when using Express, in the "res" object there is "cookie" so you can do something like:

```
res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
```

In the API routes offered by NextJS in Next 9, when looking at res, this does not exist. Is there a way to set the cookie for a response object in a Next API Route function?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Adapted from offical repo middleware [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/api-routes-middleware/utils/cookies.js), you can set `Set-Cookie` header via `res` like so:

```js
import { serialize } from 'cookie';

function (req, res) {
   // ...
   // setHeader(headerName: string, cookies: string | string[])
   // can use array for multiple cookies
   res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize('token', 'token_cookie_value', { path: '/' }));
}
```

Comment: how about multiple cookies ? is it working to do that multiple time?

Comment: @Afsanefda, you can use array in second param like so:
`res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
    serialize('foo', 'bar', { path: '/' }),
    serialize('hello', 'world', { path: '/' })
]);`

Comment: _hint_, if you are using typescript, you should install type definitions as a dev dependency: `npm i -D @types/cookie`

Comment: You can set also HttpOnly cookie with serialize('token', token, { httpOnly: true })
https://github.com/jshttp/cookie/blob/master/index.js#L91

Comment: must we use serialize, I don't have cookie installed

Comment: @Chukwu3meka it's optional just a utility function. Just write your cookie as string. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: Thanks to you @Kevin Law, I got to understand this

Comment: Hi guys i return error like: res.setHeader is not a function

Answer (score 7):

I just found an easier way to do this in Next.js, though with a library -- **[cookie-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next)**

run  `npm install --save cookies-next`

> If you are using next.js version greater than 12.2.0 you need to use cookies-next version 2.1.0 or later

### Client Example

```js
import { getCookies, setCookie, deleteCookie } from 'cookies-next';

// we can use it anywhere

getCookies();
getCookie('key');
setCookie('key', 'value');
deleteCookie('key');
```

### Server example

> getServerSideProps **or** pages/api

```js
import { getCookies, getCookie, setCookie, deleteCookie } from 'cookies-next';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  setCookie('server-key', 'value', { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 });
  getCookie('key', { req, res });
  getCookies({ req, res });
  deleteCookie('key', { req, res });
```

#### notice the difference in client and server. For server side, you must pass { req, res } to the next-cookie, else it won't work