# NextJS api cookies are not set in response header

Tags: laravel, next.js, oauth

I'm using NextJs getInitialProps trying to refresh the access token.

```
if(!access_token && ctx.req) {
  try {
    await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/refresh_token',
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: refresh_token ? { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie } : {}
    })

    console.log(ctx.res.headers)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response)
  }
}
```

and this is the api endpoint:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { serialize } from 'cookie'

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost/oauth/token', {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: req.cookies.refresh_token,
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope: '*',
    })

    const { access_token, refresh_token, expires_in } = response.data

    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
      serialize('access_token', access_token, { path: '/', maxAge: expires_in, httpOnly: true, sameSite: true }), 
      serialize('refresh_token', refresh_token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, sameSite: true })
    ])

    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'yess' })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.response.data.message)
  }
}
```

but when I log the response headers the cookies are not set. Chrome also doesnt show the cookies. Am I missing a step? Maybe because its server side rendering I have to do it another way? I've honestly been stuck with this for 3 days now and I've tried everything (I think so at least) and with no success. Its bugging me as I have no idea to setup proper auth in NextJs.

Comment: any luck with this? im stuck with the same problem

Comment: This made if for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559239/cant-set-a-cookie-using-nextjs-9s-api-route

Comment: @Mr.Goferito Hey sorry for the late response. I never managed to fix it.