# Secure application in SSR pages in NextJS

Tags: security, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a SSR page in nextjs, but I want to make it available to only authenicated or the logged in user. How   to make sure this thing as the SSR is getting generated in the server and I cannot pass the token from the localstorage there.
Pls share what would you had done

I currently dont have any context to how solve this pls help .

Comment: How are you implementing authentication? Are you using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/)?

Comment: No just a simple JWT based authentication using the Passport at the backend.

Comment: You could use [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) when the user logs in, then when they made a request you can access the request cookies.

Comment: You can store the token in a cookie, which can be accessed on the server, and use it to verify the user's identity. Use the getServerSideProps method in your page component to check for a valid token and only return the data for the page if the user is authenticated or just use HOC or next-auth.

Answer (score 0):

As per koolskateguy89's comment, when you issue the client an access token (JWT), you can add a set-cookie header that tells the client to add the JWT as a cookie. Then when you request the page you are referring to from the client, make sure to include the `with credentials` property in the request (although this can vary if you are using the native fetch api).

If you wish not to set cookies, when requesting the page you wish to have auth on, you can pass the authorization header and use your token from localstorage as shown here:

```
const res = await fetch(/api/authprotected, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt-from-local-storage}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
```

Then in getServerSideProps you can parse the JWT from the request and validate it.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const token =
    (context.req.headers.authorization as string) ||
    (context.req.cookies.jwt as string);

//validate the JWT token here, send error if not auth'd

};
```

Note: ideally, the authorization of a token should be done in the `middleware.ts` file. Having authorization logic on every single one of your api routes that requires it does not follow the DRY principle

Comment: I am able to send the cookie in the header from my Backend, but Next JS is not setting it in the browser. How to deal with that one ?

Comment: how are you sending the cookie to the client, whats the line of code

Comment: `res.cookie("access-token",token,{
                    expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 1000),
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        httpOnly: true,
                })

                return res.json({
                    id:user.id,
                    email:user.email,
                    username:user.username,
                    access_token: this.jwtService.sign(user),
                    photo:user.photo,
                    bio:user.bio
                })`

On server side.

Comment: `const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user", {
                username: usern,
                email: e,
                password: pass,
                role
            }, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }).`

Comment: sorry this is the best way I could have put the code.

Comment: try the methods in this link to set your cookie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559239/cant-set-a-cookie-using-nextjs-9s-api-route

Comment: `res.cookie("access-token", token, {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                }).json(res.json({
                    id: user.id,
                    email: user.email,
                    username: user.username,
                    photo: user.photo,
                    bio: user.bio
                })) ` On the server side

Comment: `const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user", {
                username: usern,
                email: e,
                password: pass,
                role
            }, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            })`  I did some digging now its working fine. the above one I implemented in the server this one in the nextjs side.

Comment: no problem, if it answered your question please mark it as answered :)