# How Do I Create a “Set-Cookie” Response Header in a next.js API Endpoint That Uses “SameSite=Lax” AND Can Be Called From an External Website?

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, setcookie, response-headers

I have two websites that exist as independent stacks. I need to find a way to pass a unique token directly from my main website ("dev.MAIN_SITE.org") to an auxiliary website ("dev.AUX_SITE.org"). The MAIN SITE makes requests from the user's browser in javascript and the auxiliary site runs in next.js / javascript. My goal is to ensure that a user can identify themselves once on the MAIN SITE and can then carry that identification with them (via an encrypted ID token) when they later visit the auxiliary.

I am aware that I could pass the token via a url argument, however, I am not a fan of this solution since I want this process to be as invisible to users as possible. Requiring users to sign in again when visiting the auxiliary site is also not an option for this project. Finally, merging both websites into a single site or domain is also NOT an option due to the nature of the project.

My way of achieving this thus far has been to set up an API endpoint on AUX SITE `pages/api/accept_user_token.js` (which runs on AUX SITE's server) that returns a header containing a "Set-Cookie" command to set the token as an AUX SITE cookie in the browser the request originates from. This way, when a user is on MAIN SITE I can make their browser send their token to this endpoint, have it receive a "Set-Cookie" header (which the browser will automatically intercept and resolve), and create an AUX SITE cookie in their browser while they are technically still on MAIN SITE. This way when they do visit AUX SITE, I can simply check their browser for this cookie to identify them.

The code for this endpoint is as follows...

```
import Cors from 'cors';
import axios from 'components/axios';

const corsMiddleware = Cors({
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    // Test different allowed origins just in case
    const allowedOrigins = [
      'http://localhost',
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'https://MAIN_SITE.org',
      'https://*.MAIN_SITE.org',
      'https://AUX_SITE.org',,
      'https://*.AUX_SITE.org',
    ];

    // Check if the requesting origin is in the list of allowed origins
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  credentials: true, // Enable credentials
});

// Helper function to apply the middleware
function runMiddleware(req, res, fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        reject(result);
      } else {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  await runMiddleware(req, res, corsMiddleware);

  // Extract the token parameter from the request body
  const token = req.body.token;

  const expirationTime = new Date();
  expirationTime.setTime(expirationTime.getTime() + 3600 * 1000); // Expires in 1 hour

  // Attempt to set token using different Domain and SameSite configurations to see what works
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie',
    [
      `session_token=${token}; Domain=.AUX_SITE.org; Secure; Path=/; Expires=${expirationTime.toUTCString()}; SameSite=Lax`, // Results in cookie being rejected
    ]
  );

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Token successfully set!' });
}
```

I then make a call to this endpoint from the client's browser on MAIN SITE like such.

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ token }),
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

I have tested this in Chrome and have only had it successfully set AUX SITE cookies when "SameSite=None" and the cookie is "Secure". However, [Safari utilizes stricter security requirements and thus does not allow for cookies to be set when "SameSite=None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559239/cant-set-a-cookie-using-nextjs-9s-api-route), instead requiring "SameSite=Lax" at minimum. If I try to run my current code in Safari or Chrome I can see all of my "Set-Cookie" headers in the "network" tab of the developer tools (so I know that they are reaching the browser at least) but the cookie values are not being set. I believe that Safari is simply refusing to set any AUX SITE cookies in this context due to them not complying with security requirements.

I have tested this setup locally by running instances of my websites on localhost:3000 and localhost:3001 and making a call from one to the other. The "Set-Cookie" configuration that worked in this context (in Safari OR Chrome) involved setting "SameSite=Lax" and specifying "Domain=localhost" (see "session_token_localhost_domain" in my code).

So then we arrive at my underlying issue: I am unable to find a "Set-Cookie" configuration in the api endpoint of a next.js website that uses the "SameSite=Lax" and can function properly if called by an external domain. I have tried multiple different configurations for this (altering values for "Domain", "Secure", "HttpOnly", etc.) and I can't seem to find one that actually leads to cookies being set.

I believe that they are all being rejected on grounds of the "domain" value not being correct (I can see a "*" next to the domain of rejected cookies in the Chrome dev tools). I've tried using ".AUX_SITE.org" and ".MAIN_SITE.org" as domain values in a deployed environment but this has not lead to cookies being set.

Is the issue that Safari will ALWAYS consider cookies being created in this context to be third-party and thus will reject them? I believe the "Domain" value should correspond to AUX SITE, however, I'm not sure if the request originating from MAIN SITE is interfering with this somehow.

I also cannot rule out the possibility that something in my CORS settings is preventing these cookies from being set.

Since the token is encrypted and offers no access sensitive information I am not overly concerned about security in this context. If possible, I am also happy to use Session or Local storage in the browser if that is easier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!